# Deploy c++ shared library with specific headers

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm creating a c++ shared library for an internal personal project and I'm using cmake for linking/compilation process. Right now my CMakeLists.txt file looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(borges)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(include)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_library(borges SHARED ${SOURCES})

install(TARGETS borges DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)
```

I have succesfully compiled my files, but know I'm a little concerned about "encapsulation". I was wondering if there is a way to only expose certain .h files, as there are some classes which wouldn't make much sense to use outside of my library context. Something like "private" classes of the library and only expose those classes that people would use externally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already know this based on your question, but the your current CMakeLists.txt does not install any headers. To install specific ones, all you need to do is list the .h files that you want to install and pass them to CMake's install command:

```
set(HEADERS_TO_INSTALL foo.h bar.h borges.h)
# ...
install(FILES ${HEADERS_TO_INSTALL} DESTINATION include)
```

On a side note, it's much better practice to use relative paths in your `install(DESTINATION)` arguments.  These will be interpreted relative to the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable, whose default value is actually `/usr/local`.

If you want to actually disallow people from linking to the internal classes, then you may want to look into GCC's [visibility control](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)